# Futurize module - running for first time, Windows 10 cmd, get Errno 22

Tags: python, windows-10

Just installed futurize, on Windows 10. From cmd, tried to run on all .py files in directory, by three different ways. Still got error, see below.

1. Regular Windows path:

   ```
   C:\Users\cumminjm>futurize --both-stages -w "C:\Users\cumminjm\Documents\scripts\*.py"
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
   RefactoringTool: Can't open C:\Users\cumminjm\Documents\scripts\*.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\cumminjm\\Documents\\scripts\\*.py'
   RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
   RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
   RefactoringTool: Can't open C:\Users\cumminjm\Documents\scripts\*.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\cumminjm\\Documents\\scripts\\*.py'
   ```
2. Windows path with forward slashes instead:

   ```
   C:\Users\cumminjm>futurize --both-stages -w "C:/Users/cumminjm/Documents/scripts/*.py"
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
   RefactoringTool: Can't open C:/Users/cumminjm/Documents/scripts/*.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/cumminjm/Documents/scripts/*.py'
   RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
   RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
   RefactoringTool: Can't open C:/Users/cumminjm/Documents/scripts/*.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/cumminjm/Documents/scripts/*.py'
   ```
3. CD'd to directory, and ran like this:

   ```
   C:\Users\cumminjm\Documents\scripts>futurize --both-stages -w *.py
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
   RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
   RefactoringTool: Can't open *.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '*.py'
   RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
   RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
   RefactoringTool: Can't open *.py: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '*.py'
   ```

Comment: Perhaps futurize does not support wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, though in my case I'm using an absolute path, I couldn't get any combination of back/forward slashes, quotes, *.py or **/*.py to work in a situation like this:

```
futurize --stage1 c:\mydir\**\*.py
```

In the end, this worked for me, which was fine because I am happy to convert all files in subdirectories recursively:

```
futurize --stage1 c:\mydir\
```